# Doraemon - Episode where Suneo goes to Holland on Tour

Tags: doraemon

I can't remember the episode, but the storyline went as follows:

Suneo went to Holland on a tour, and boasted to everyone about it. He also unfortunately lost his camera there. Nobita goes to Doraemon and says that he wants a Holland tour too. Doraemon comes up with a gadget that shows them scenes of any place in the world live, and he invites all his friends to his home. As Doraemon shows them the scenes in Holland (Madurodam, canals etc), Suniyo sulks while Nobita is very happy. Soon, they come across a bench with a camcorder on it and they zoom in, and it turns out it's Suneo's camcorder. Suneo leaps at the camcorder, only to punch a hole through Nobita's sliding door and break the gadget, and not get his camcorder back.

A link to the episode if available online would be helpful.

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **episode 778, "The Sight Seeing Window" (かんこうりょこう窓),** which was first broadcast on August 24, 1984 in Japan.

---

Reference:

- [Reddit - r/Doraemon - Whats this episode?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Doraemon/comments/1532jmf/whats_this_episode/)
- [Pixiv Encyclopedia - 観光旅行まど](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E8%A6%B3%E5%85%89%E6%97%85%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A9) (Japanese)
- [Wikipedia - List of Doraemon (1979 TV series) episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doraemon_(1979_TV_series)_episodes)
- [Simkl - Doraemon Episode 778](https://simkl.com/anime/38799/doraemon/episode-778/)